# Create a custom login in wakanda 1.1.3

Tags: wakanda

I am creating a Angular2 application in which i need a custom login instead of the existing directory login So, I added the following code and created some new files and code as the following

i added a new file login.js under the backend location with the following code

```
directory.setLoginListener("loginFuction","Admin");
```

I made changes to my require.js as the following

```
function loginFunction(email,password){
    console.log("Call is being made to the backend");
    var u = ds.User.find("email : 1" ,email);
    console.log(u);
    if(!u){
        return false;
    }else{
        var token = currentSession.promoteWith("Admin");
        if(u.password == password){
            var theGroups = [];
            switch(u.role){
                case 'Admin':
                    theGroups.push('Admin');
                    break;
                case 'Users':
                    theGroups.push('Users');
                    break;
            }

            var connectTime = new Date();

            return {
                ID : u.ID,
                name : u.email,
                fullName : u. fullname,
                belongsTo : theGroups,
                storage:{
                    time : connectTime
                }
            };

        }else{
            return {
                error : 1024,
                errorMessage : "invalid login"
            }
        }
    }


};
```

when i call the loginFunction from my normal component like

```
this.wakanda.directory.login('adithya@gmail.com','adithya').then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

I am getting an error stating

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Directory.login: Unauthorized

All the table are being made global access, and everything is being made as public.

Can anyone help me with this solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting the console logs, that you added to your login listener? Make sure you have set the authentication type in your solution `settings.waSettings` file on solution level to custom. Your user query in your login listener should be `ds.User.find("email == :1", email);` and you don't need to promote the current session in your login listener, since you already did that in the `directory.setLoginListener("loginFuction","Admin")`

Comment: `directory.setLoginListener("loginFuction","Admin")` needs to be part of the bootstrap file (not some random login.js in the backend) http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Users-and-Groups/Directory/setLoginListener.301-871936.en.html

Comment: Stefan is right, the `setLoginListener` needs to be inside a bootstrap file.

Comment: I am not getting the value which i have written in the console, 
i gave the setting.waSettings to be custom,

Comment: i have added the setLoginListener under my bootstrap.js file too

Comment: It can also be a CORS problem (https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/61, where is your server, are CORS enabled?) or even the fact that you are using wrong credentials (check it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact method of creating the custom login in wakanda studio 1.1.3 is of the following we have to make change in the function call present in the bootstrap.js like the following

```
directory.setLoginListener("loginFunction");
```

by removing the "Admin" as the second parameter .